# Microsoft Graph API - Request Photo by size

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking at the Microsoft Graph API Beta for Users/Photo operations documentation and I am comparing it to the Outlook REST API. In the Outlook REST Beta there is the option of retrieving a photo by size.

`GET https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('{user_id}')/photos('{size}')/$value`

I do not see a way in Graph API to request a photo by size. Is there anyway to do this? If not, is this a planned feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a doc error and we will fix it.  The equivalent request (see below) is supported today in Microsoft Graph.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('{user_id}')/photos('{size}')/$value
```

Comment: Is it possible to this in the Microsoft Graph Sdk?

Answer (score 7):

When using the Microsoft Graph SDK you can do it this way:

```cs
var graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient();
var photoStream = await graphClient.Users[userId].Photos["120x120"].Content.Request().GetAsync();

// or

var photoStream = await graphClient.Me.Photos["120x120"].Content.Request().GetAsync()
```

Comment: The supported sizes of HD photos on Microsoft 365 are as follows: 48x48, 64x64, 96x96, 120x120, 240x240, 360x360, 432x432, 504x504, and 648x648. Photos can be any dimension if they are stored in Azure Active Directory.